# How to debug hyperledger composer web?

Tags: debugging, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Have started to play around with hyperledger composer web recently.  I do not have a local composer set up, am on composer-playground.mybluemix.net completely.

To debug a transaction code, I tried using console.log, but that didn't work. i.e. no output in browser console.

What is the best way to debug here ? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

console.log output in a Transaction Processing script does go to the Browser Console using composer-playground.mybluemix.net.  It can be viewed using `Ctrl-Shift-I` in Chrome or Firefox.

If you are using Playground locally, and connecting to a Fabric, then the log output is written to the Docker Container.

Comment: Thank you Thathcer for your help. Sorry was out of action hence couldn't reply earlier. Console.log does work. Apparently in my case, when I was editing the script file and updating network, the changes weren't being reflected.  So I had to start afresh to get the changes with debug statements to reflect.  Haven't been able to find a way to force playground to stop using cache and pick up the updated files.